# Canvas - How to make line pass through a point

Tags: javascript, canvas

[This](http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/pXj3X1x.png) is what I have right now:

[image: How it is]

I want to make it like [this](http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/Z5Bqz8x.png):

[image: How is should be]

The blue line as you can see passes through the center(400,400). The start of the blue line is not fixed, it moves according to data that the user enter.

How do I add this blue line and make it pass through the center?

Sorry for my bad English, working on that :)

Halfon

Comment: You should at least show some code you tried to create this line.

Comment: I do not think that he should show some code ...  Like me... one newbee...  We have real dificulties making questions, Most of all... maibe.... becouse...  we do not know what are we talking about...  AND if we new, there aren't questions....

Answer (score 4):

[Use mathematics](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=equation+of+line+given+2+points).

Let the center co-ordinates be `(Cx, Cy)`, which in your case are `(400, 400)`. Let the user's co-ordinates be `(Ux, Uy)`.

The equation of the line passing through the center from `(Ux, Uy)` would be given by the equation:

`y - Cy = slope * (x - Cx)`, where `slope = (Cy - Uy) / (Cx - Ux)`.

Now, to draw the line from `Ux` to some x co-ordinate, say `Px`, simply use the equation to calculate `Py = Slope * (Px - Cx) + Cy`, then draw the line from `(Ux, Uy)` to `(Px, Py)`.

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(Ux, Uy);
context.lineTo(Px, Py);
context.stroke();
```

Comment: This code seems to be very easy to study!  can you give us some jsfidle code?  I realy apreciate that!   I am studing this!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Simply draw the line through the center point and extend its length. It's completely unclear what the length of the line is because you failed to provide any code, so I'm just doubling it in the example.

To calculate the end points, just subtract the starting x/y coordinates from the doubled x/y coordinates of the central point.

I wrote you a dynamic example which takes the mouse coordinates as a starting position, but the same principle applies if you only have a single static point from the user input. Try it here:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerPoint;

function setSize() {
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
  centerPoint = {x: canvas.width / 2, y: canvas.height / 2};
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
  context.lineTo(centerPoint.x * 2 - e.offsetX, centerPoint.y * 2 - e.offsetY);
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
  context.stroke();
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  centerPoint = {x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY};
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
})

window.addEventListener('resize', setSize);
setSize()
```

```css
canvas {width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;}
body {margin: 0}
p {position: absolute; pointer-events: none}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<p>Click anywhere to set the center point (dead center by default)</p>
```

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto No problem, good luck with the canvas stuff! I have quite a few canvas answers here on Stack Overflow. :)